# Call a function once user handles push notification registration alert

Tags: objective-c, xcode, push-notification, uialertview

These codes will be called when a page loads.

```
UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert);
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Now I would like to present the next view controller as soon as the user handles the alert. Is it possible? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

### Update

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(go)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
}

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
     UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert);
     UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}

- (void)go
{
    TutorialViewController *tvc = [[TutorialViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:tvc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

This seems to work. I'm wondering if the code will be efficient?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit tricky, but it's possible.  The alert for notification permissions is a system alert, which means your app resigns active when it's shown, and you get a `application:didBecomeActive` call when the user dismisses it.

So the basic technique is to set a flag in your app delegate when you're about to trigger the alert.  In your `application:didBecomeActive` implementation, check the flag and perform whatever work you need to do.

This is not 100% foolproof, as the app might be resigning active for a different reason.  You can mitigate some of this by also tracking whether the app went to the background after resigning active.  You should also be sure that the alert will be shown when you ask for permissions.  If the user has previously answered, no alert is shown.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've updated the question with a working code. Could you give it a look?

Comment: That's the basic idea.  The one thing you haven't done is any mitigation for other reasons the app may go inactive while on that view controller.  That's the purpose of the flag that I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

When The App is brought into running state via Notifications..This method is fired

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

You can then retrieve the notification received from the `launchOptions dictionary` and open the appropriate screen.

Hope this helps.